# React native UseEffect fetching data with Navigation 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am struggling to fetch data from anywhere using React useEffect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { GOOGLE } from "../GooglePlacesKeys";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";
/**
   * 
    "latitude": 37.324746,
    "longitude": -122.02160463,
  },
   */
export default PlacesScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      fetchNearbyPlaces();
      if (!loaded) {
        fetchNearbyPlaces();
        setLoaded(false);
      }
      console.log("Places On Mounting", places);

      return () => {
        setLoaded(false);
      };
    }, [loaded])
  );

  //   console.log(places);
  const fetchNearbyPlaces = async () => {
    const latitude = 37.324746;
    const longitude = -122.02160463;
    let radius = 5 * 1000;

    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude},${longitude}&radius=${radius}&type=restaurant&key=${GOOGLE.API_KEY}`;

    await fetch(url)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(({ results }) => {
        let arrPlaces = [];
        for (let googlePlace of results) {
          let place = {};
          let myLat = googlePlace.geometry.location.lat;
          let myLong = googlePlace.geometry.location.lng;
          let coordinate = {
            latitude: myLat,
            longitude: myLong,
          };
          place["placeTypes"] = googlePlace.types;
          place["coordinate"] = coordinate;
          place["placeId"] = googlePlace.place_id;
          place["placeName"] = googlePlace.name;
          place["vicinity"] = googlePlace.vicinity;
          place["icon"] = googlePlace.icon;
          arrPlaces.push(place);
        }
        setPlaces(arrPlaces);
        setLoaded(true);
      });
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>PlacesScreen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Home"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

So I am using React navigation 5, that's why i am using useFocusEffect to fetch the data every time I navigate to the Places screen. But the problem is when I do the code above I get infinite loop but when I do this code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { GOOGLE } from "../GooglePlacesKeys";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";
/**
   * 
    "latitude": 37.324746,
    "longitude": -122.02160463,
  },
   */
export default PlacesScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
//   const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      fetchNearbyPlaces();
      console.log("Places On Mounting", places);
      return () => {
        // I did here
        setPlaces([]);
        // also I tried to not do any thing.
      };
    }, [])
  );

  //   console.log(places);
  const fetchNearbyPlaces = async () => {
    const latitude = 37.324746;
    const longitude = -122.02160463;
    let radius = 5 * 1000;

    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude},${longitude}&radius=${radius}&type=restaurant&key=${GOOGLE.API_KEY}`;

    await fetch(url)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(({ results }) => {
        let arrPlaces = [];
        for (let googlePlace of results) {
          let place = {};
          let myLat = googlePlace.geometry.location.lat;
          let myLong = googlePlace.geometry.location.lng;
          let coordinate = {
            latitude: myLat,
            longitude: myLong,
          };
          place["placeTypes"] = googlePlace.types;
          place["coordinate"] = coordinate;
          place["placeId"] = googlePlace.place_id;
          place["placeName"] = googlePlace.name;
          place["vicinity"] = googlePlace.vicinity;
          place["icon"] = googlePlace.icon;
          arrPlaces.push(place);
        }
        setPlaces(arrPlaces);
        // setLoaded(true);
      });
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>PlacesScreen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Home"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

And my logs is

`Places On Mounting Array []`

Thanks.

Comment: Your second code snippet is in the right direction. It seems your log statement is printing before your async function may have done anything, so that may be a red herring. Try replacing your focus hook with code that just calls fetchNearbyPlaces() and nothing else, also do not update the state from this hook. Just let your fetchNearbyPlaces() update the places state when it fetches them.